# Is it possible to remove column from the GetTableSql() in BIML

Tags: biml

I use the GetTableSql() function in BIML a lot, but I often need to remove some columns from this function before it executes. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

You'd have to write your own Extension method to do so. Looking through the code, you might be better off just scrubbing the column(s) from results of the method call - it just depends on what you're looking to do.

The current `GetTableSql` method is an extension method that chains a call to `EmitTableScript` which in turn calls a number of methods to build out the returning SQL. At least in the BimlStudio product, EmitTableScript is in `Varigence.Biml.CoreLowerer.Capabilities.TableToPackageLowerer` class in BimlExtensions.dll

After a bit more thinking, what might be an even better, less support headache would be to create a clone of the table node and then remove the columns you don't want.

Code approximately

```
var table0 = this.RootNode.Tables[0];
var tablePrime = table0;

// I don't have a biml project handy so this section is a guess
tablePrime.Columns.Clear();
// Might be AddRange if this method exists
// Remove all the columns that start with ignore, as an example of filtering columns
tablePrime.Columns.Add(table0.Columns.Where(x => !x.name.StartsWith("ignore"));

// end guess block    
var sql = tablePrime.GetTableSql();
```